# How to click a button in an iframe using Seleniumbase

Tags: python, web-scraping, captcha, seleniumbase

I'm trying to enter my username and password credentials in a given website but it seems to have pretty robust bot detection.  I'm using seleniumbase thinking that it would bypass bot detection but it still ask for the user to click the "I am not a robot" checkbox.

My bot can locate the checkbox and click it by switching to the iframe.  The "Proceed" button is within the same iframe but my bot cannot locate the element to click it.

Error message:
*Exception has occurred: NoSuchElementException
Message:
Element {#progress-button} was not present after 7 seconds!*

I tried locating the Proceed element using find_element / xpath but that did not work.

How can I locate the element and click through it?

```
from seleniumbase import Driver
from random import randint
from time import sleep

# Variable Defintions
LoginURL = 'https://www.tesla.com/user/login'
UserName = 'xxx@xxxx.com'
Password = 'xxxxxx'

# Log in to website 
browser = Driver(uc=True)
browser.get(LoginURL)
    
sleep(randint(5,8))

# Enter username
UserNameField = browser.find_element('xpath','/html/body/div[1]/main/div/div/form[1]/div/div[2]/input')
UserNameField.send_keys(UserName)

browser.uc_click("#form-submit-continue")

# Click through bot verification checkbox
if browser.is_element_visible("#sec-text-container"):

    browser.uc_switch_to_frame("#sec-cpt-if")
    browser.uc_click("#robot-checkbox")

    # ERROR: Cannot locate button to click through
    browser.uc_click("#progress-button")
```

[image]